# check date between fdate and tdate if its there load seprate table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Hi Friends I have small doubt in sql server please tell me how to solve 
Tables :
`patient:
pid  |   Date     | Name 
100  | 2015-01-01 |Abc
101  | 2015-02-20 |banu
102  |2015-03-14  |hari`

`

```
Address:

Pid  |   Fromdate  |  ToDate     |  Address
100  |  2014-12-31 | 2015-02-01  |   Hyd
101  | 2015-02-20  |2015-02-20   |   Bang
102  |  2015-04-10 |2015_05_20   |   Chen`
```

Based  on this above table I want check patient date between from date and todate in address table .
if patient date between fromdate and todate In addtress that records i want load separate temparay table 
in tempresult table  I  required only   name  column from patient and for identification that record add one 
columns status.
f patient date not between fromdate and todate In addtress that records i want load same  temparay table 
in tempresult table .
Finaly Temp table Result look like below:

```
Tablesname :##TempResult

Name |  Status
Abc  | Outdate
banu | Indate
hari | outdate
```

### I tried like below

```
alter procedure test
as

begin

IF

OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Result') IS NOT NULL
drop

table ##Result
create

table ##Result
(

Name

varchar(50),
Filter

varchar(10)
)

insert

into ##result
select

a.name, 'InDate' as Filter from patient a join address b on a.patientnumber=b.patientnumber
where

a.date <=b.fromdate and a.date >=b.todate
insert into ##result
select

a.name, 'outDate' as Filter from patient a join address b on a.patientnumber=b.patientnumber
where

a.date <>b.fromdate and a.date <>b.todate
select * from  ##result
end
exec test 

select * from  ##result
```

its given correct values.but performance wise its not good way
due records check 2 times(entired records) please tell me any other way to
achive this issue.
another way i Tried like

```
alter procedure [dbo].[FindDate]
as
begin
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Address') IS NOT NULL
drop table ##Address
create table ##Address
(
id int identity(1,1),
patientnumber int,
fromdate date,
Todate date,
Address varchar(50)
)
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Result') IS NOT NULL
drop table ##Result
create table ##Result
(
Name varchar(50),
Filter varchar(10)
)

insert into ##Address 
select patientnumber,fromdate,todate,address from Address
----------------------------------------------------

declare @acount int
select @acount=count(id) from ##Address


declare @i int
set @i=1

while @i<=@acount
begin

declare @pn int,@fromdate date,@todate date,@address varchar(50)

select @pn=patientnumber,@fromdate=fromdate,@todate=Todate from ##Address 
where id=@i
set @i=@i+1
end

declare @bcount int
declare @in int
set @in=1

while @i<=@bcount
begin
select @bcount=count(1) from patient

where patientnumber=@pn and [patient].[date] between @fromdate and @todate

if @bcount<>0

begin
insert into ##Result
select name,'InDate' as Filter from patient
where patientnumber=@pn
end
 else
print '4'
begin
insert into ##Result
select name,'OutDate' as Filter from patient
where patientnumber=@pn
end

---set @i=@i+1;
select * from ##Result
end
end
```

this one not give good result and its take more time for 3 records.
please tell me how to achive this issue in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things about this approach that raise questions with me but in the interest of brevity I will just show a few small improvements to get you going.

First thing is that the sample address table is missing a PK, that is very often a bad idea and when the number of rows increase it might really hurt performance. In this specific sample it doesnt really change anything but leaving such a gap could hurt you later on. (or maybe you just left it out for the sample, i dont know). Anyway this would address the problem:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Address] ADD [aid] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL;
```

Regardless of the PK your current plan looks like this:
[image]
And it's not pretty. For something rather simple it consists of way to many operations and when the amount of data grows performance might really be horrible. Aside from looking at the bigger picture and changing the data model and such there is a simple step that can help you by changing the proc like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[test]', 'P') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[test];
    END;
GO 
CREATE PROCEDURE [test]
AS
    BEGIN
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Result') IS NOT NULL
            DROP
TABLE [##Result];
        CREATE
TABLE [##Result]
            (
              [Name] VARCHAR(50) ,
              [Filter] VARCHAR(10)
            );

        INSERT  INTO [##Result]
                SELECT  [a].[Name] ,
                        CASE WHEN [a].[Date] <= [b].[Fromdate]
                                  AND [a].[Date] >= [b].[ToDate] THEN 'InDate'
                             WHEN [a].[Date] <> [b].[Fromdate]
                                  AND [a].[Date] <> [b].[ToDate] THEN 'outDate'
                        END AS [Filter]
                FROM    [dbo].[patient] [a]
                        JOIN [dbo].[Address] [b] ON [a].[pid] = [b].[Pid];

        SELECT  *
        FROM    [##Result];
    END;
```

This gives the following plan:
[image]
As you can see this is a lot less steps and should improve performance to some degree.